# Unable to select view/ menu item using withId method in UI testing options menu using Espresso

Tags: android, kotlin, integration-testing, android-espresso

I am working on an Android Kotlin project. I am adding UI tests written using the Espresso framework into my project. But in my tests, I cannot select the menu item of the options menu within the action bar using withId() method.

Following is how I added the menu into the action bar in the activity.

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.event_list, menu)

        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
             R.id.action_logout -> {
                 ApplicationController.instance.clearLoginData()
                 finish()
             }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

This is the event_list.xml in the menu resource folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_logout"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

This is how my test method

```
@Test
fun itWipesOutLoginDataWhenLogoutMenuItemIsTapped() {
    FakeEventService.SCENARIO_UNDER_TEST = 0
    this.eventListActivityRule.launchActivity(null)
    openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>())

    onView(withId(R.id.action_logout)).perform(click())
}
```

As you can see in the test method, I am selecting the menu item by using withId() method. But when I run the test, I am getting the following error.

```
androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.example.memento:id/action_logout
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView{2582e16 VFED.VC.. ........ 0,0-686,168}

View Hierarchy:
+>PopupDecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=686, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params={(740,98)(686x168) gr=TOP START CENTER DISPLAY_CLIP_VERTICAL sim={state=unchanged} ty=APPLICATION_SUB_PANEL fmt=TRANSLUCENT surfaceInsets=Rect(112, 112 - 112, 112) (manual)
fl=LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH SPLIT_TOUCH HARDWARE_ACCELERATED FLAG_LAYOUT_ATTACHED_IN_DECOR
pfl=WILL_NOT_REPLACE_ON_RELAUNCH LAYOUT_CHILD_WINDOW_IN_PARENT_FRAME}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+->PopupBackgroundView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=686, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@de56b69, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+-->MenuDropDownListView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=686, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@4044e8f, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->ListMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=686, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams@393b6fa, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->AppCompatImageView{id=2131230882, res-name=group_divider, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@70144ab, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+---->LinearLayout{id=2131230818, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=686, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@d648c6, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+----->RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=574, height=76, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@4a503dd, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=56.0, y=46.0, child-count=2}
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For somebody who will search an answer here, the easiest way to interact with menu is by using [Barista](https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista) library. It provides methods like `clickMenu(R.id.menu_item)` or `openMenu()` for easy menu interactions. The click one works even if the item is hidden inside the overflow.

I have example tests with it in my Android UI [testing tutorial](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/android-app-ui-tests-with-cucumber-espresso-barista-1604021fed6c).

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `withId` when selecting menu items because the menu is inflated with their own views and ids, and so your id `action_logout` will never exist in the view hierarchy (`NoMatchingViewException`):

[image: menu]

Try a different view matcher instead, use `withText` for example:

```
openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>())
onView(withText("your_menu_item_logout_string")).perform(click())
```

Also note when a menu is opened (popup), all subsequent test interactions will be performed within the menu until it is dismissed, so you don't have to worry about conflicting matches in the background view.

Comment: Hi, my question is if the other view outside of action bar has the same test, would there be a conflict?

Comment: Will it conflict if there's a same text outside the menu? The answer is no. If you look at the error log you provided, the root view is `PopupBackgroundView` which is the menu, so `onView(withText("..."))` will be performed within the menu view.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. It works. Do you want to post an answer to that? I can accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and tried using openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu() as shown in Aaron's answer but would get a "no overflowmenubutton" error. However, his answer confirmed what I had thought was the reason that the test couldn't find the menu's widget that I actually wanted to test. So, I tried a few other things that I thought would access the Toolbar and thus allow the widget to be found and got success with the following:

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_toolbar)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
onView(withId(R.id.my_toolbar)).check(matches(hasDescendant(withId(R.id.action_add))));
onView(withId(R.id.action_add)).perform(click());
```

My guess is that this sequence identifies the Toolbar and then allows the widget, the "action_add" button, to be found via its ID. When I run this test the target Intent is opened, thus verifying that the "action_add" widget was indeed clicked by perform(click()).

I hope that this helps someone in the same predicament.